# How to configure gitlab to use existing postgres server

Tags: postgresql, nginx, gitlab, centos7

When installing [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com) by default Nginx and Postgres .. among other things are installed regardless of whether you have them already or not. So since I have these two already, I am trying to configure gitlab to use them, I have done this for Nginx, Using:

```
$ vi /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:

# Disable GitLab's nginx completely
nginx['enable'] = false

# Set external web user which is 'nginx' on CentOS 7
web_server['external_users'] = ['nginx']
```

but I need to know how to do the same `postgres`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this doc](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/database.md#using-a-non-packaged-postgresql-database-management-server), put this in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` :

```
# Disable the built-in Postgres
postgresql['enable'] = false

# Fill in the connection details for database.yml
gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = 'postgresql'
gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = 'utf8'
gitlab_rails['db_host'] = '127.0.0.1'
gitlab_rails['db_port'] = 5432
gitlab_rails['db_username'] = 'USERNAME'
gitlab_rails['db_password'] = 'PASSWORD'
```

And run this command to apply this values : `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. Also you need to seed your database if you choose an external one. This command will do it with omnibus-gitlab: `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:setup`

Comment: The remote database user (foo in this example) must be able to create databases and be a superuser during the `gitlab-rake` command. You may have to install `postgresql-contrib` on remote server.

Comment: Shouldn't this be port 5432 for Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

Pierre's solution is fine for new installs, but if you already have data in the DB, you need to migrate instead. The cleanest, most fail-safe way is to create a backup, which contains the DB too:

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

The backup file will be located at `/var/opt/gitlab/backups`.

Alternatively, you can try:

```
sudo -u gitlab-psql /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/pg_dumpall --username=gitlab-psql --host=/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql
```

Then you can import the DB into the existing Postgres instance with:

```
psql -f /tmp/database.sql
```

Then you need to reconfigure and restart too:

```
gitlab-ctl start && gitlab-ctl reconfigure && gitlab-ctl restart
```

It starts with `start` because you need to make sure GitLab is running. That's because, however weird that sounds, `reconfigure` fails if GitLab is stopped:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - connect(2) for /var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.socket
```

Which is kinda counter-intuitive, since traditionally you make changes to the config while the instance is stopped.

---

**But** either with migrations or clean installs, the problem comes with the first GitLab upgrade:

```
gitlab preinstall: Automatically backing up only the GitLab SQL database (excluding everything else!)
Dumping database ...
Dumping PostgreSQL database gitlabhq_production ... pg_dump: server version: 10.4; pg_dump version: 9.6.8
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
Backup failed
[FAILED]
```

As it instructs you, you gotta:

```
sudo touch /etc/gitlab/skip-auto-migrations
```

So now the package will update successfully, but GitLab still won't work anyway, you gotta again:

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

To do this automatically:

```
yum install yum-plugin-post-transaction-actions
echo 'gitlab-ce:any:/bin/gitlab-ctl reconfigure' > /etc/yum/post-actions/gitlab-ce.action
```

For all the nitty-gritty details, please see:

- [Migrating GitLab from internal to external PostgreSQL](https://noobient.com/post/175239582451/migrating-gitlab-from-internal-to-external)
- [Upgrading GitLab with external PostgreSQL](https://noobient.com/post/175240426691/upgrading-gitlab-with-external-postgresql)